# Delete all the contents of list using javascript REST or CSOM

Tags: 2013, rest, csom, jsom

I want to delete all the contents of list using javascript

I tried

**REST**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/sites/hr/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Groups')/items?$filter Title neq x&$Top=20000",
    type: "DELETE",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "IF-MATCH": "*"
    }       
})
```

and **CSOM**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
   list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList'),
   query = new SP.CamlQuery(),
   items = list.getItems(query);
ctx.load(items, "Include(Id)");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator(),
        simpleArray = [];
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        simpleArray.push(enumerator.get_current());
    }
    for (var s in simpleArray) {
        simpleArray[s].deleteObject();
    }
    ctx.executeQueryAsync();
});
```

Both don't seem to work

What is wrong with the snippets?

For the Rest I am getting 400 error but when I open the url its fetching restults

For the CSOM I don't get any errors but the items are not deleted

Answer (score 3):

Try it as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Groups')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        for(var item in items){
            var itemUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Groups')/getItemById(" + item.ID + ")";
            deleteItem(itemUrl);
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});

function deleteItem(itemUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: itemUrl,
        type: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("deleted item")
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Using JSOM, you can delete multiple item in batch:

```
function deleteListItems() {

    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestList');


    for(var i = 0; i<= 100; i++){
        //assuming the IDs are available, else need some validation  
        var oListItem = oList.getItemById(i);  
        oListItem.deleteObject();
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Items Deleted');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
deleteListItems();
```

Reference - [Batch operations using JSOM](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/batch-operations-using-javascript.html)

Using CAML query, you do it as below:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
var customList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test'); 
var itemColl; 

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
    //set your caml query here
   camlQuery.set_viewXml( 
         '<View><Query><Where><Eq>' + 
           '<FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>x</Value>' + 
         '</Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 
     itemColl = customList.getItems(camlQuery); 

clientContext.load(itemColl);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(deleteitemColl, onGetitemCollFail);

function deleteitemColl() {

    var itemArray = new Array();
    var listItemEnumerator = itemColl.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        itemArray.push(item);
    }

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
        customList.getItemById(itemArray[i].get_id()).deleteObject();
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onDeleteitemCollSuccess, onDeleteitemCollFail);
}

function onGetitemCollFail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Unable to get completed items. Error:' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function onDeleteitemCollSuccess() {
    console.log('Completed orientations have been deleted.');    
}    

function onDeleteitemCollFail(sender, args) {
    console.log('Unable to delete completed items. Error:' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks
any way to delete with one server hit?

Comment: Have updated answer, to delete multiple items using JSOM. Ensure that item id is available, else do a caml query and then use the above code to delete items

Comment: it throws an error
Unable to delete completed items. Error:The request uses too many resources.
the list has around 13K items

Comment: The ajax request will only fetch batches of 100. You can make it iterate through all items wrapping the GET request in a function (getData), and then call it from the succes part: if(data.d.__next)
    {
     url = data.d.__next;
     getData(); 
    }

Answer (score 2):

**Deleting a list item using CSOM:**

To delete a list item, call the `DeleteObject()` method on the object. The following example uses the `GetItemById()` method to return the second item from the list, and then deletes the item.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
 class DeleteListItem
  {
    static void Main()
    {   
        string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
        ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById(2);

        oListItem.DeleteObject();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
    }
  }
}
```

**Reference:**

[JQuery](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3074/delete-list-items-csom-sharepoint-online.aspx)

**Deleting a list item using REST API:**

```
function deleteListItem()  
{  
 $.ajax  
 ({  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('companyInfo')/items(7)",  
    type: "POST",  
    headers:  
    {  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "IF-MATCH": "*",  
        "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"  
    },  
    success: function(data, status, xhr)  
    {  
        retriveListItem();  
    },  
    error: function(xhr, status, error)  
    {  
        $("#ResultDiv").empty().text(data.responseJSON.error);  
    }  
 });  
}
```

**Reference:**

[How to delete list item in Parent site using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216074/how-to-delete-list-item-in-parent-site-using-rest-api)

[How to delete list item using REST services](http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2014/12/sharepoint-2013-how-to-delete-list-item.html)

Answer (score 2):

Delete all SharePoint ListItems using javascript [SPServices library](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/index.html) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function deleteListItems() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Groups", // List name
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr("ows_Id"));
        // Delete list item
        $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Groups", // List Name
        batchCmd: "Delete",
        ID: id,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            console.log('List item has been deleted');
        }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

</script>
```

Refrences:

- [SPServices GetListItems](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/core/web-services/Lists/GetListItems.html)
- [SPServices DeleteItem](http://amitkumarmca04.blogspot.in/2017/03/delete-item-in-sharepoint-list-or.html)

Comment: `var id = parseInt($(this).attr("ows_ID"));` work for me .