# How to delete list item in Parent site using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

am trying to delete the list item in Parent site. i have a button in subsite when i click on the button i need to delete the list items based on query match. am able to update with but not able to delete.
here is my code snippet here i am passing the item IDs in an array. 
below code is working for same site(current logged in site).
my code is showing like operation success but not deleting the items? don't know what was wrong with my code

```
function deleteiteminListAllDocs(itemIDarr)
 {
    for(var j=0; j<itemIDarr.length;j++)
    {
        var itemID=itemIDarr[j];
        console.log(itemID);
        $.ajax  
        ({  
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/site/rootweb/lists/GetByTitle('ProductInfo')/items('"+itemID+"')", 

type: "DELETE",  
            headers:  
            {  
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                 "If-Match": "*"
            }, 
            success: function(data, status, xhr)  
            {  
               //retriveListItem();  
                    console.log("SUcess");
            },  
            error: function(xhr, status, error)  
            {  
            console.log("error");
               // $("#ResultDiv").empty().text(data.responseJSON.error);  
            }  
        }); 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code it did not work for me. Then i tried my code and it worked. The problem is in your URL.

use `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl` instead of `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` and try again.

```
var itemID=itemIDarr[j];
    console.log(itemID);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/site/rootweb/lists/getByTitle('ProductInfo')/items('" +itemID + "')",
            type: "DELETE",
            headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
                },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: its working . and same time ' _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl ' also working
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the itemID.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/site/rootweb/lists/GetByTitle('ProductInfo')/items("+itemID+")"
```

Comment: its not working. my code is showing like operation success but not deleting the items? don't know what was wrong with my code

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: am not getting any error, as per code its logging success message but delete operation not happening

Comment: when you hit the url in browser are you getting the item?

Comment: yes am getting, before doing this operation first am getting the item IDs based on some query and passing those ids to this method in a Array.

Comment: thats fine. if your getting the item in broswer after hitting url, then you should be able to delete it. Check permission of list on parent site.

Comment: Install the Chrome Extension SharePoint Insider and verify your are using the correct endpoint